# FixedUpdate is called before Start of the same MonoBehavior

Tags: unity-game-engine

I Have a MonoBehavior doing something like below:

```cs
public class MyMonoBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;

    private void Start()
    {
        m_RigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        m_Rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.one); // May throw NullRefrenceException
    }
}
```

The MyMonoBehavior is attached to a GameObject which is created at runtime.
Occasionally, `m_Rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.one);` throws NullRefrenceException.
It seems that **FixedUpdate** run before **Start**. Is it a bug?

According to the [Unity3d documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html):

> **Before the first frame update Start:**
>
> - Start is called before the first
>     frame update only if the script instance is enabled.
>
> For objects added to the scene, the Start function will be called on
>   **all** scripts before Update, etc are called for any of them. Naturally,
>   this cannot be enforced when an object is instantiated during
>   gameplay.

So it seems above **all** scripts include "MyMonoBehavior" its self? So its FixedUpdate can be executed before its Start.

Is my understanding correct? Or is this a bug of Unity3d?

My Unity3d version is 2017.3.1f1

Comment: `FixedUpdate` is the periodical update callback of the ***physics engine***. `Update` is the ***frame*** based update, i.e. the display update. They work independently to each other. The only thing guaranteed by documentation is: "`Start` is called before the first ***frame*** update..." Try `Awake` and see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: ...`OnEnable` might be the better choice since the rigid body component might not be initialized on awake. Or you have to do workaround `if(m_RigiBody) ...` [FixedUdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html): "This function is called every fixed framerate frame, ***if the MonoBehaviour is enabled***." So `OnEnable` should be called first.

Comment: I wrote that on the fly without doing any test. I would transform this into an answer if you can confirm that it works.

Comment: btw.:  `GetComponent<Rigibody>();` Did you mean `Rigidbody` or have you created your own extended component?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone note however that also in https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html there is a graphic that clearly shows that also `Start` is called before the `Physics` block so that should actually not be the issue, right?

Comment: @derHugo I would not rely on that figure. It also implies that physics would be looped before visualisation frames are updated once. There is no independent parallelism in that scheme. Reliable are usually the specs. Since I've never found specs for unity3d, the manual in text form is the authoritative source for me.

Comment: I frequently experienced that the Unity3d documentation is really bad. However, investigating this issue I found that most of the documention examples do use `Start` to cache a `Rigidbody` reference. A few tutorials on the Unity site also use `Awake`. Even the documentation of the `Rigidbody.AddForce` method does use `Start`. So it **should** work. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

Answer (score 1):

That's why you have `Awake`. Basically, you should do initialization that's specific to your object in `Awake`, and leave interaction with other objects for `Start`. `Awake` is called as part of the object instantiation process, so I highly doubt you'd run into similar problems.

Comment: But `m_RigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` is only getting a reference which usually should be in place already so there should be no difference actually between using `Awake` or `Start` for getting it. (Ofcourse I would also use `Awake` if I know that another component will later ask to pass the reference on e.g.)

Comment: @derHugo OP's problem is that FixedUpdate is called **before** the reference has a chance to get assigned.